# PersistenceContext and EntityManager nullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jta

I have problem with EntityManager in my application. I create EntityManager with @PersistenceContext annotation. But when I try to get data by my Dao I'm getting errors.

Here are my files:

*persistence.xml*

```
<persistence version="2.1"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*Resources.java*

```
package com.app;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {

  @Produces
  @PersistenceContext(name = "primary")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

and then I'm injecting EntityManager into my BaseDao class:

*BaseDao.java*

```
package com.app.dao;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public abstract class BaseDao {

  @Inject
  protected EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

*ClubDao.java*

```
package com.app.dao;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import com.app.entity.Club;

@ApplicationScoped

public class ClubDao extends BaseDao {

  public Club getClubById(long id) {
    String jpql = "FROM Club where id = :id";
    TypedQuery<Club> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, Club.class).setParameter("id", id);
    return query.getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

And when I use endpoint for this data I'm getting error on Glassfish console:

```
[2021-07-22T21:31:13.951+0200] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1626982273951] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[com.app.AppConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.app.AppConfig threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.EEResourceProducerField.create(EEResourceProducerField.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:758)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:858)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:358)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:369)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:140)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at com.app.dao.ClubDao$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getClubById(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.service.ClubService.getClub(ClubService.java:24)
    at com.app.service.ClubService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getClub(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.assembler.ClubAssembler.getClub(ClubAssembler.java:16)
    at com.app.assembler.ClubAssembler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getClub(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.controller.ClubApiController.getClub(ClubApiController.java:22)
    at com.app.controller.ClubApiController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getClub(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

I read few topics here and also on other pages, but nothing helped me. Please give me some advices, what should I change or what I have forgot to add.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "unitName" instead of "name" in the PersistenceContext-Annotation.
And you don't need the Resources Class, just inject the EntityManager everywhere you need.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: This does not help. I changed my `BaseDao` class with suggestion which you posted here and removed `Resources` class. Now I am getting another error - debugger goes into `getClubById` method in `ClubDao`, but there `entityManager` is null. I also tried to put this `entityManager` with `@PersistenceContext` in `ClubDao` - without `BaseDao` and there is same result.

Comment: Then I can only try to guess. I recognized the hibernate-provider in your persistence-xml. Glassfish is normally using eclipse-link. Do you have the dependency for the hibernate-entitymangaer in your Pom? Maybe you can remove the provider and the hibernate-related property from the persistence.xml. just to check if the Entitymanger is injected then.